# Bootstrap transparent navbar in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just wanted to remove background in my bootstrap navbar. So I've added navbar-fixed-top to main wrapper.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
```

Now it's looking good for desktop version.

[image]

But in mobile version, menu bar toggle icons is not appearing.

[image]

And I don't want a fix nav bar. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this code....**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

**You Just include this css not html than work fine:**

```
.navbar-toggle{background:red;}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar{background:white;}
```

Comment: Now it's working! Thanks.. But it's still fixed to top.

Comment: Remove nav tag this class navbar-fixed-top

Comment: I removed navbar-fixed-top from nav. But the background is visible again.

Comment: remove navbar-default class. Than add a simple css .navbar{background:green;}